# Non Surjective Transformation with dense range

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

I have already proved that the transformation is 1-1 but there's a problem in proving that it's range is dense and that it is not Surjective.

If I can show that every sequence (element)in $\ell^2$ is arbitrary close to some of the range elements. Then I am done but how to prove that.

Kindly help!!
 thanks and regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The range contains $-e_1,e_1-e_2,...$ and since it is a subspace it contains each $e_n$. hence the range is dense. Now consider $(\frac 1 n)$. Note that $(B-I)(a_1,a_2,...)=(a_2-a_1,a_3-a_2,...)$. Suppose $(B_I)(a_n)=(\frac 1n )$. From the equation $a_n-a_{n-1}=\frac 1 n$ we get $a_n =a_1+\frac 1 2 +\frac 1 3+...+\frac 1 n$, Clearly this is a contradiction because LHS $\to 0$ and RHS $\to \infty$. Hence $(\frac 1 n)$ is not in the range of $B-I$.

Comment: Impressive...Can you tell me about the thought process       you had to approach the question.

Comment: When you write down the equation $(B-I)(a_n)=(b_n)$ and try to solve it for $(a_n)$ you will see that partial sums of $b_n$'s come into the picture. That suggests using the series $\sum \frac 1 n$ whose partial sums tend to $\infty$.

Comment: I got your point thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to proving denseness is also a nice exercise in geometric Hahn Banach, so I will write it out to give a different flavor to the other answer:

Say $B-I=A$ does not have a dense image. This means $\exists y\in \overline{A(l^2)}^C$. Because $\overline{A(l^2)}$ is a closed and convex subspace, there exists by geometric Hahn Banach a function $f=(f_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\in (l^2)^*\approx l^2$, such that:

$$f|_{\overline{A(l^2)}}=0\Rightarrow\sum f_i A(x)_i=0 \quad \text{and} \quad f(y)=\sum f_i y_i>0$$

Taking $x=y$ in the first sum yields:

$$f|_{\overline{A(X)}}(y)=\sum f_i (y_{i+1}-y_i)=0\Rightarrow f(y)=\sum f_i y_i=\sum f_i y_{i+1}$$

Taking $x=By$ yields:

$$\sum f_i(y_{i+2}-y_{i+1})=0\Rightarrow f(y)=\sum f_i y_{i+1}=\sum f_i y_{i+2}$$

Suppose, $f(y)=\sum f_i y_{i+n)}$ as the induction hypothesis. In general, for $x=B^n y$, we have:

$$\sum f_i(y_{i+n+1}-y_{i+n})=0\Rightarrow f(y)=\sum f_i y_{i+n}=\sum f_i y_{i+n+1}$$

Therefore, we have by Holder's inequality:

$$|f(y)|=\left|\sum f_i y_{i+j}\right|\leq \lVert f \rVert \lVert (y_{i+j})_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \rVert_2$$

Because $y\in l^2$ and $j$ is an arbitrary natural number, the righthandside may become arbitrarily small and we conclude $f(y)=0$ which is absurd. Hence $\overline{A(X)}=l^2$